# Trying to get strings from managed code back to C++

Tags: c#, c++, xamarin, marshalling

(sorry if this has been asked before, but most of the examples that I've seen are passing data from managed -> native, not the other way around).

Short question: How do I fetch a string from the managed world from within native C++ code?

Long question + background: 
I'm working with some legacy C++ code that formerly had the capability to get and set name/value string pairs (to greatly simplify the design). I wanted to move that name/value pair mechanism up into C# managed code with the rest of our application, so I put in function callbacks in the C++ world that call up into the managed code for getting and setting. The C++ function pointer types are as follows:

```
typedef int (GetConfigParamCallback)(const char* paramName, char* value);
typedef GetConfigParamCallback* LPGetConfigParamCallback;

typedef int (SetConfigParamCallback)(const char* paramName, const char* value);
typedef SetConfigParamCallback* LPSetConfigParamCallback;
```

As you can see, the tricky one is the get, where I want to provide memory to the caller to fill up. This will be the managed code moving forward.

These callbacks are represented by delegates in the C# world like so:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int Native_GetConfigParamCallBackMethodDelegate(
  string paramName, StringBuilder paramValue);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int Native_SetConfigParamCallBackMethodDelegate(
  string paramName, string paramValue);
```

And then my GetConfig wrapper function in the managed code that acquires the values looks like this (and puts the correct value into paramValue as seen by my debugging):

```
static int GetConfigParamCallBackWrapper(
  string paramName, 
  System.Text.StringBuilder paramValue)
{
  string valueTemp = // Fetch the string value here

  if (valueTemp == null)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  paramValue.Append(valueTemp);
  return 1;
}
```

So when the managed C# starts up, it sets these callback functions in the native world. Then, I have the native code run a series of what amounts to unit test methods that are getting and setting these strings. Now, on desktop this works fine, but when I try to run this on iOS with a Xamarin built app, the string comes back to the native world as garbage, AFAICT.

I’ve tried doing manual marshaling with IntPtr as well, and also no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can marshal the string as a BSTR:

**C++:**

```
typedef int (GetConfigParamCallback)(const char* paramName, BSTR* value);
typedef GetConfigParamCallback* LPGetConfigParamCallback;

// Usage:
LPGetConfigParamCallback pCallback = // ...
CComBSTR value;
int result = (*pCallback)("...", &value);
```

**C#:**

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int Native_GetConfigParamCallBackMethodDelegate(
    string paramName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string paramValue
    );

static int GetConfigParamCallBackWrapper(
    string paramName, 
    ref string paramValue
    )
{
    string valueTemp = // Fetch the string value here

    if (valueTemp == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    paramValue = valueTemp;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the native code must be compiled for iOS, Android, and PC, which means that I can't use MS only code - it has to be a common type. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a slightly less pretty, but valid solution, thanks to this excellent blog post: http://randomencoding.tumblr.com/post/48564128118/returning-a-string-from-a-c-callback-to-c.

I used an IntPtr and did manual Marshaling:

```
static int GetConfigParamCallBackWrapper(
    string paramName, 
    IntPtr paramValue)
{

   string valueTemp = // Acquire valueTemp here. 

    IntPtr sPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(valueTemp);
    try
    {
        // Create a byte array to receive the bytes of the unmanaged string
        var sBytes = new byte[valueTemp.Length + 1];
        // Copy the the bytes in the unmanaged string into the byte array
        Marshal.Copy(sPtr, sBytes, 0, valueTemp.Length);
        // Copy the bytes from the byte array into the buffer passed into this callback
        Marshal.Copy(sBytes, 0, paramValue, sBytes.Length);
        // Free the unmanaged string
    }
    finally 
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sPtr);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling [StringToHGlobalAnsi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) instead of [StringToHGlobalUni](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni.aspx)? You already have a unicode string. There's no reason to make it subject to interpretation. All the more since that interpretation is based on volatile per-thread state. Or am I missing something here?